# what condition we need to use "." in command line?

Tags: command-line

a question -
in some case, I saw command line like this

## . ./test.sh

I'm curious why use "." before "./test.sh"
what condition we have to use "." before a command?

Comment: I have read both threads above. @Micheal that one you mention as duplicate fails to explain adequately the consequences on the environment vars of sourcing a script. I agree more with Ulrich, but even then the mention of forking or not bash is buried in the 4th answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `. ./test.sh` is similar to running `source ./test.sh`. It's not running the file `test.sh` as an executable. Instead it's running it's contents line by line into your current shell. So it could for example also modify your current environment.

Answer (score 1):

Running `. ./test.sh` is the same as `source ./test.sh`. It runs the script in the current shell rather than a subshell (i.e. it does not fork). This may change variables of same name in the calling script, and it will leave variables and functions which were defined in `./test.sh` also defined and visible after the call in the calling script.